# How to visualise data with numbers and text in heatmap?

Tags: python, pandas, data-visualization, heatmap

Suppose I have the following variables:-

```
words = ["He is a good artist hopefully"]
specs = ["Spec1", "Spec2", "Spec3",
           "Spec4", "Spec5",  "Spec6"]

scores = np.array([[0.1, 0.039, 0.1223, 0.0105, 0.0604, 0.0899]])
```

What will possibly be the best way to relate `specs` with `scores` if I want to show this in a colour coded/heatmap form?

Comment: Maybe a [word cloud](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/wordcloud-python)?